# A double sum identity for Catalan constant

Tags: definite-integrals, summation, catalans-constant

While playing around with the problems [here 1](https://brilliant.org/problems/handle-with-care-3/?ref_id=1577956) and [here 2](https://brilliant.org/problems/handle-with-care-ii/?ref_id=1577959), I came to found the double sum identity for [Catalan constant, G](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant)
by making few change in those problems.  ie

> $$ G= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
> \frac{1}{(2m+n)^2}\left((-1)^m-(-1)^{m+n}+(-1)^n\left(1+\frac{2m}{(m+n)}+\frac{m^2}{(m+n)^2}\right)\right)$$

To prove this  I had to evaluate 3 different summation ( just apply the linearity) which makes work quite tedious and length for me. That is I had to evaluate the following summation (simplified form)

> $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(-1)^m}{(2m+n)^2}-\frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{(2m+n)^2}+\frac{(-1)^n}{(m+n)^2}\right)\tag{1}$$

**Evaluation  of initial sum**
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{(2m+n)^2}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^m\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2m+n)^2}$$

If we   write the inner  sum in series  form we  notice  that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2m+n)^2}= \underbrace{\dfrac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(m+n)^2} }_{\text{}S_1}+\underbrace {\sum_{n=1,3,5\cdots}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2m+n)^2}}_{\text{} S_2}$$  and hence  have  $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^m}{(2m+n)^2}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^m \underbrace{\dfrac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(m+n)^2} }_{\text{}S_1}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} (-1)^m\underbrace {\sum_{n=1,3,5\cdots }^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2m+n)^2}}_{\text{} S_2}$$ we now   evaluate  the $S_1$ and $S_2$  separately  as follows $$\begin{align}4S_1 =\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^m}{(m+n)^2}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} (-1)^m\left(\dfrac{1}{m^2}+\dfrac{1}{(m+1)^2}\right)\\ +\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^m \left(\dfrac{1}{(m+2)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(m+3)^2}\right)+\cdots \\=\underbrace{\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{1}{(m+1)^2}-\dfrac{1}{m^2}\right)}_{\text {Telescopes}}+\underbrace{\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{1}{(m+3)^2}-\dfrac{1}{(m+2)^2}\right)}_{\text {Telescopes}}+\cdots \\ =-\left(\dfrac{1}{1^2}+\dfrac{1}{3^2}+\dfrac{1}{5^2}+\cdots \right) =-\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(2m-1)^2}\\=-\left(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{m^2}-\dfrac{1}{4}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{m^2}\right)=-\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}\end{align}$$ therefore we have $S_1=-\frac{\pi^2}{32}$ and we are left to evaluate  $$ \begin{align} S_2= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1,3,5\cdots }^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^m}{(2m+n)^2}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} (-1)^m\left(\dfrac{1}{(2m+1)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(2m+3)^2}\right)\\ +\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^m \left(\dfrac{1}{(2m+5)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(2m+7)^2}\right)+\cdots \\=\underbrace{\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{1}{(2m+3)^2}-\dfrac{1}{(2m+1)^2}\right)}_{\text {Telescopes}}+\underbrace{\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{1}{(2m+7)^2}-\dfrac{1}{(2m+5)^2}\right)}_{\text {Telescopes}}+\cdots\\=-\left(\dfrac{1}{3^2}+\dfrac{1}{7^2}+\dfrac{1}{11^2}+\cdots\right)=-\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(4m+3)^2}\\=-\dfrac{1}{4^2} \psi^1\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right) =-\dfrac{1}{16}\left(\pi^2-8G\right)\end{align}$$  or  $$\begin{align} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(4m+3)^2} = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{m^2}-\left(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(2m)^2}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(4m-3)^2}\right)\\= \dfrac{\pi^2}{8}-
\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^m}{(2m-1)^2}+\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(4m+3)^2}\right)\\\implies 
 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(4m+3)^2} =\dfrac{\pi^2}{2\times 8}-\dfrac{G}{2}  \end{align}$$ thus $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^m}{(2m+n)^2}=-\dfrac{\pi^2}{32}+\dfrac{G}{2}-\dfrac{\pi^2}{16} =\dfrac{G}{2} -\frac{3}{32}\pi^2$$  Similarly,  evaluating the middle and last  summation  i came up with the closed form $\displaystyle -\frac{G}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{32}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{\pi^2}{8}$  giving us $$\frac{G}{2}-\frac{3}{32}\pi^2+\frac{G}{2}-\frac{\pi^2}{32}+\frac{\pi^2}{8}=G$$

Now my query is, *How to evaluate/ relate the double summation without evaluating the  each individual summation*?

One of the way I had solved it using integration trickes which is solved [here](http://www.ssmrmh.ro/2019/11/04/amazing-identity-48/) by Sergio Esteban, Argentina.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

A solution using $1/a^2=\int_0^1 x^{a-1}l(x)\,dx$ for $a>0$, where $l(x)=-\log x$ for brevity.
\begin{align*}
(1)\quad&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty(-1)^m\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1-(-1)^n}{(2m+n)^2}+\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(m+n)^2}
\\&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{2(-1)^m}{(2m+2n+1)^2}+\frac{(-1)^n}{(m+n)^2}\right)
\\&=\int_0^1\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\big(2(-1)^m x^{2m+2n}+(-1)^n x^{m+n-1}\big)\right)l(x)\,dx
\\&=\int_0^1\left(2\frac{-x^2}{1+x^2}\frac{1}{1-x^2}+\frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{1+x}\right)l(x)\,dx=\color{blue}{\int_0^1\frac{l(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx}
\\&=\int_0^1\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n x^{2n}\right)l(x)\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}=G.
\end{align*}

Comment: (initially deleted because it seems to duplicate the existing efforts)